# installing nodejs module doesnt give me the command

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to run pixel-ping and running into trouble. I followed these instructions:

http://documentcloud.github.io/pixel-ping/
and it mentions that `Installing Pixel Ping gives you the pixel-ping command.` but when I type `pixel-ping path/to/config.json` it returns `-bash: pixel-ping: command not found`
 I am not sure why it would say that any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I have both nodejs and npm installed I have other modules working perfectly. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I am not sure why someone voted -1 I would really appreciate some help or guidance.

Comment: Did you restart your terminal? Also might need to install it globally

Comment: I did restart my terminal it didn't work. what do you mean by install it globally ?

Comment: curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh

Install Pixel Ping via NPM:

sudo npm install -g pixel-ping

Restart shell

Comment: also make sure ~/npm/bin is in the Path

Comment: what do you mean is in the path where? do I cd to /npm/bin first then execute the commands ?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Comment: done. still command not found. npm works fine it does download the files and place them in node_modules folder but I cant execute pixel-ping

Comment: oh -g solved it many many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

Install Pixel Ping via NPM:

```
sudo npm install -g pixel-ping
```

Restart shell

Also ensure
~/npm/bin is in the Path